# JQuery Select 4 Minimum Value from Array List

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab 4 Minimum values from a array list.

Example

```
var ArrayList =[2,3,4,76,23,14,99,54,21]
```

I would like to grab 4 Numbers so result should be 2,3,4,14

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick search for "Sort an array" and "Get first X from array" should solve this.

Comment: `var res = [ArrayList[0],ArrayList[1],ArrayList[2],ArrayList[5]];`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var array =[2,3,4,76,23,14,99,54,21];
var newarray=[];
var min;
for(i=0;i< 4;i++){
    min = Math.min.apply(Math,array); 
    newarray.push(min);
    array.splice(array.indexOf(min), 1);
}
alert(newarray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what the actual...

Comment: "Try this" is not a good answer, explain what's going on! (also, using a static index in a loop typically is bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

first sort the list from least to greatest and splice the resulting string from the index 4 to the length of the array to get the minimum values

```
function myFunction() {
    arrayList.sort(function(a,b){ return (a-b)}).splice(4,arrayList.length);
}
```